# iPhone8 Showing Pictures On Device Even Though I Removed All Photos

Tags: data-recovery, iphone, photos

[image]

I don't get it.  I removed all my pictures from my iPhone8 but iPhone Storage is still showing pictures are in the iPhone8.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you purged the Recently Deleted, they will stay for 30 days. If you did, reboot the phone. If that doesn't work, make a new backup & restore from it.

Comment: & I just realised this is off topic here - needs migrating to ask different… where it will be a dupe ;)